# Deploying play app to OpenShift

Tags: playframework, openshift, playframework-2.4

I have developed a simple CRUD application using play framework 2.4.x. I would like to deploy it to Openshift.

I found this [link](https://blog.openshift.com/supporting-play-framework-on-openshift-with-the-diy-application-type/) but I guess things have changed a lot as it was written in 2012. Any experiences of deploying play app to OpenShift or a document pointers or screencasts would help.